# Does ios5 has any api to speak selected text for accessibility programmatically?

Tags: ios, accessibility, text-to-speech

In iOS5 I can enable "Speak selection" feature in (Settings > General > Accessibility > Speak Selection), but I can use this only when I tap to highlight text and tap speak option. I want to facilitate my user (Rss reader app) with one click button that will speak out the whole article. Is this possible in iOS5 ?

Comment: Well, I guess you can alter you question to iOS6 ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**No**,at lease not in public iOS API.

For **third party** api, you can use [flite on iOS](https://bitbucket.org/sfoster/iphone-tts)

For **private** API (unable to sell on App store), according to this [post](http://www.ahmed-essam.com/2010/11/ios-sdk-text-to-speech-in-one-line.html), following should work.

```
[[[NSClassFromString(@"VSSpeechSynthesizer") new]autorelease] 
   startSpeakingString:@"I like to speak everywhere"];
```

Comment: Apple should release it soon :(,  it would be very beneficial. Most (all) third party api not supported Thai language which is my user language.

Comment: How do you use it (the private API)? What should I include on the project because I gets an error when tring to build "No known instance method for startSpeakingHere..."